# Is deployment to a test environment a part of Continuous Integration?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, agile, continuous-delivery

I have checked quite a lot of sources and it still remains unclear to me: is deployment to a test environment part of CI, or is CI just about committing often and keeping the mainline bug-free and integrated? Some say this, some say deployment to a target environment is a part of CI.

Otherwise I do not seem to see the difference between CI and Continous Delivery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous integration might or might not require something you'd consider a deployment to a test environment. The main point of CI is that automated tests are run on a version of the software to ensure that that version i's ready to be deployed to the next step (QA, staging, production, or whatever the next step in one's process is). So the software is deployed if that's needed for the software to be tested and not if it's not.

There's always a test environment of some kind, because the automated tests have to run on some computer(s), but the code might or might not get there through what you'd consider a deployment. For example, if an application is in an interpreted language, running automated tests might require nothing more than copying the source to the test environment and running a script, not actually deploying.

Whether deployment is needed for automated testing depends on what kind of automated tests the application has. If it only has unit tests, no deployment is needed. If it has full-stack integration tests, deployment might or might not be needed depending on the integration test framework. For example, the integration testing framework which is a part of Rails runs a test-specific version of a Rails server for tests to talk to, so those test don't require deployment. On the other hand, other frameworks might not provide that support, so the application would have to be deployed to the test environment to give full-stack integration tests something to run against. Or a CI build might include automated performance tests; those would certainly need to run against the application deployed to a test environment.

Comment: Thanks. But what is meant by test? Automated one? Most systems still need manual validation done by testers (e.g. systems with GUI where also accessibility, usability etc. need to be checked). And what is the difference to COntinous delivery then?

Comment: Yes, automated tests. I made that clearer in my answer. An app may have manual tests, but that's not part of CI. As for CD, if your app has manual tests that have to be run before deploying to production, you're not doing CD. You could CD to production and manually test there, though.

Comment: Also if our app (multi-tier, DB, Java middleware and Flex UI) runs its unit and integration tests, it is still CI. Then it deploys to our SIT environment for our testers to perform some tests - the deployment is triggered manually in Jenkins - is that still part of CI somehow? Some sources I read (like Pro :NET Best practices) mentioned Deployment as a step in CI.

Comment: That's certainly something you can do, and I have done, as part of your CI process. It's not a necessary part of CI, however.

Comment: Maybe one more question, if you dont mind - why all sources mention code analysis after the unit tests? I would expect that static analysis is the first step to detect issues and not after the unit tests are run.

Comment: Two possible reasons: 1) static analysis isn't fundamental to CI and automated tests are; it's natural to discuss the fundamental part first 2) static analysis results are often not pass-fail, but interpreted by humans, so there's no point in running them on a version of the software for which the tests don't pass.